# Any issues with a SSRS 2008 front-end going to a SQL 2005 cluster back-end

Tags: sql-server, cluster, ssrs

We want to install SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 on Server "A" which is not clustered. We want to use Server B to host the Reporting Services databases. Server B is a SQL 2005 cluster in Active/Passive mode. Any reason why this shouldn't work?

We don't have a good test environment for this, otherwise we'd just try it.

Thanks.

Comment: Watch out for licensing. Unfortunately, the SSRS 2008 server will require a SQL Server license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes you can use SQL 2005 backend for SSRS 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms156016.aspx). Quote:

> You can use an instance of the
>   Database Engine from SQL Server 2005
>   or SQL Server 2008 to host the
>   databases.

In the olden days, you could not host SSRS 2005 databases onto SQL Server 2000.